# Hibernate search across two entities without an embedded index

Tags: elasticsearch, hibernate-search, quarkus

I am trying to use Hibernate Search 6 and elastic search
A simple example of what I am trying to build is as follows.

I have a `Book` entity, which has information like `title`, `authorName`, `genre`, `price`
I have a `Shop` entity which has information like `shopName`, `phone`, `email`, `location`
I have a "joining table" which does a many to many mapping between nooks and shops. ( A book can be at many shops, and a shop can have many books)

I am trying to do a search by name and location, ideally to find a book at a location nearest to the input. The standard book-author example in the documentation requires a `IndexedEmbedded` annotation, which is not really possible in my case because I am using a joining table. 
Is there an alternative approach to solve this problem

Comment: "which is not really possible in my case because I am using a joining table" => This seems dubious. Please show us the relevant parts of your ORM mapping (Book class, Shop class, their associations, and the class modeling the joining table if there is one).

Comment: @yrodiere I think I understood where I went wrong. I  will try this out and post back here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My entities

```
    @Indexed
    public class Book extends PanacheEntity{
      public String title;
      public String authorName;  
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.REMOVE })
      public List<BookShopRelation> bookShopRelation = new ArrayList<>();
    }  


    @Indexed
    public class Shop extends PanacheEntity{
      public String name;
      public String city;  
      @OneToMany(mappedBy = "shop", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.REMOVE })
      private List<BookShopRelation> bookShopRelation = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Indexed
    public class BookShopRelation extends PanacheEntity{
    @JoinColumn(name = "shop_id")
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
        @IndexedEmbedded
        private Shop shop;

        @JoinColumn(name = "offer_id")
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
        @IndexedEmbedded
        private Book book;
    }
```

For me what was key was to understand, was that the relation table could be indexed and used as the basis for the search

```
 List<BookShopRelation> result = Search.session(entityManager)
                .search(BookShopRelation.class) .predicate(f ->
                        pattern == null || pattern.trim().isEmpty() ?
                                f.matchAll() : 
                                f.simpleQueryString()
                                    .fields("book.title").matching(pattern) 
                    ) 
                    .fetchHits(size.orElse(20));
```